# How to add PIL images to Excel sheet using Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, python-imaging-library

I have a list of PIL images, which look like this

```
[
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=695x500 at 0x1E7275D2DF0>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=695x500 at 0x1E7275F8970>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=695x500 at 0x1E729B7A490>
]
```

And I'd like to take each PIL.Image from the list and add it to the excel file as the original image using Pandas. Is that possible?

Current output is:

[image]

What I want is the PIL.image replaced with the actual image.

Comment: I doubt doable with pandas. Maybe openpyxl. I could be wrong.

Comment: Indeed. Inserting an image to excel with [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=image#inserting-an-image) or [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html?highlight=image#insert_image). Notice that both need your images to be stored somewhere. So you might need to [save your PIL images](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save) before, if not already.

Comment: @WholeBrain For openpyxl, seems that it's unnecessary to save the PIL image now according to the [code](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/_modules/openpyxl/drawing/image.html), you can pass PIL image directly.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you need an engine to do this, such as `openpyxl` or `xlswriter`, and store your PIL images in your working directory, so that you can insert them to an excel file (as a `.png`, for example).

Install `xlswriter` in your environment. For instance, `pip install xlswriter` and then you can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image

images = [Image.new('RGB', (200, 200)) for _ in range(3)] # 3 empty PIL images

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('excel_file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for i, image in enumerate(images):
    image.save(f"img_{i}.png", "PNG") # Save your image before inserting
    worksheet.insert_image(0, 6*i, f"img_{i}.png")
    
writer.save()
```

You'd have to change `0, 6*i` to an appropriate row, column pair depending on where you want them to be, and so they don't overlap.